# Criar tabela HTML e mostrar dados, usando PHP

Tags: php, tabela-html

Gostaria de ver se alguém me consegue ajudar neste problema de criar uma tabela HTML em php.

```
<?php
      <p><b>Alvará: </b></p>
      <p>Alvará Numero: '.$exibe["AlvaraNumero"].'</p>
      <p>Alvará Validade:';
      if ($exibe['AlvaraValidade']) { 
          if (strtotime($exibe['AlvaraValidade']) < time()) {
              echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['AlvaraValidade'].'</span>';
          } else {
              echo $exibe['AlvaraValidade'];
          }
      } else { 
           echo 'N/D';
      }
      echo '</p>

      <p>Alvará Anexo: <a href="MostrarAlvara.php?id=' . $exibe['id'] . '">Ver PDF </a></p>
?>
```

Quero criar uma tabela para colocar esses dados mais organizados.

**`| Alvara | Numero | Validade | Anexo | Valor numero | Data | Ver PDF |`**

Alguém me consegue ajudar a fazer algo assim?

Comment: Não sei se posso marcar como duplicado, mas, veja um assunto recente e muito semelhante: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20745/criar-tabela-html-usando-php

Answer (score 3):

Seu código possui diversos erros de sintaxe, segue um exemplo de código *comentado*, para que você use como base para criar sua tabela.

```
<?php
    //crie uma variável para receber o código da tabela
    $tabela = '<table border="1">';//abre table
    $tabela .='<thead>';//abre cabeçalho
    $tabela .= '<tr>';//abre uma linha
    $tabela .= '<th>Alvara</th>'; // colunas do cabeçalho
    $tabela .= '<th>Numero</th>';
    $tabela .= '<th>Validade</th>';
    $tabela .= '<th>Anexo</th>';
    $tabela .= '<th>Valor numero</th>';
    $tabela .= '<th>Data</th>';
    $tabela .= '<th>Ver PDF</th>';
    $tabela .= '</tr>';//fecha linha
    $tabela .='</thead>'; //fecha cabeçalho
    $tabela .='<tbody>';//abre corpo da tabela
    /*Se você tiver um loop para exibir os dados ele deve ficar aqui*/
    $tabela .= '<tr>'; // abre uma linha
    $tabela .= '<td></td>'; // coluna Alvara
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$exibe['AlvaraNumero'].'</td>'; //coluna numero
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$exibe['AlvaraValidade'].'</td>'; // coluna validade
    $tabela .= '<td></td>'; //coluna anexo
    $tabela .= '<td></td>';//coluna valor numero
    $tabela .= '<td></td>'; // coluna data
    $tabela .= '<td><a href="MostrarAlvara.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">Ver PDF </a></td>';
    $tabela .= '</tr>'; // fecha linha
    /*loop deve terminar aqui*/
    $tabela .='</tbody>'; //fecha corpo
    $tabela .= '</table>';//fecha tabela

    echo $tabela; // imprime
```

Comment: Ficou muito legal, valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
//Aqui vai a sua query, e o resultado dela vou chamar de $resultado
//Aqui verificamos se existe algum registro da query.
if(mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0) {
         echo "<table border='1'>"; //Criamos a tabela
         //Aqui criamos o cabeçalho da tabela.
         // A tag <tr> abre uma linha, enquanto a <td> abre uma célula.
         echo "<tr><td>Alvara</td>"
              ."<td>Numero</td>"
              ."<td>Validade</td>"
              ."<td>Anexo</td>"
              ."<td>Valor Numero</td>"
              ."<td>Data</td>"
              ."<td>Ver PDF</td>"
              ."</tr>"; // Fechamos o cabeçalho. 
}
```

Agora vamos a parte da exibição dos dados, continuando o código:

```
//Vamos percorrer o array, e fazer a mesma coisa que fizemos em cima.
//Montar uma linha, e as células da tabela.
while($exibe=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
$id = $exibe['id'];
//Não exibi todos os dados, agora é só você completar, colocando cada célula dentro de um <td>
     echo "<tr><td>$exibe[Alvara]</td>"
          ."<td><a href='MostrarAlvara.php?id=$id'>Ver Alvara</a></td>"
          ."</tr>";
}
// E fora do while fechamos a tabela.
echo "</table>";
```

Espero que tenha ajudado, não compilei e não sei se está funcionando, mas dá para ter uma base de como fazer.

Answer (score -3):

Use as tags de criação de tabela:

```
<table border="0">
 <tr>
  <td>Coluna 1</td>
  <td>Coluna 2</td>
 <tr>
</table>
```